# How to add a tooltip/hoverover to a filter for a grid column Extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5, sencha-architect

I have a grid panel with columns containing filters I want to add a hover on the filter. How can I achieve this. I tried adding tooltip it didn't work. Any suggestions please.

[See fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/203p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add tooltip on Filters menu item then you can override [Ext.grid.filters.Filters](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.grid.filters.Filters.html)

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.filters.Filters,{
     createMenuItem: function (menu, parentTableId) {
        var me = this,
            item;

        // only add separator if there are other menu items 
        if (menu.items.length) {
            me.sep = menu.add('-');
        }
        item = menu.add({
            checked: false,
            itemId: 'filters',
            text:me.menuFilterText,
            tooltip:'On blank space filters data with empty fields ',
            listeners: {
                scope: me,
                checkchange: me.onCheckChange
            }
        });

        return (me.filterMenuItem[parentTableId] = item);
    }
});
```

if you want to have tooltip on Search Textbox then following would do:

```
 {
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        dataIndex: 'myField',
        text: 'My Field',
        filter: {
            type: 'string',
             itemDefaults: {
                 inputAttrTpl: " data-qtip='On blank space filters data with empty fields' ",
            }

        }
    }
```

Link to forked fiddle : https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/204o
Used **Ext JS 5.1.1.451 - Neptune**

Comment: Thanks but this will apply to all the columns which contain filters right. What if I want only for one column